Problem with relative imports on locally installed package via pip: "ModuleNotFoundError" vs "ImportError"
Here is my project structure:

DIR_PROJECT

pyproject.toml
__main__.py
DIR_MODULES

module.py





content of module.py:
def f1():
    print("Module ok")

content of __main__.py:
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from DIR_MODULES import f1

def main():
    f1()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Running the __main__.py in terminal works well, but if I install this package locally by running <python -m pip install -e /path/to/DIR_PROJECT> and run installed program, it gives an error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'DIR_MODULES'
If I modify from DIR_MODULES import f1 line by adding . (from .DIR_MODULES import f1), program executes without error.
BUT now running __main__.py directly in a terminal gives an error:
"ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package"
Is there any solution to make it work in both cases so I do not have to have a copy without "." and ".." for developing and a copy with dots for installing and distributing?
I have triyd to add __init__.py in directories but this did not work.
If I understand correctly, __init__.py is not needed in recent Python versions.
I have run the __main__.py from all directories, also directly and with -m option, but still not working.
The best solution to make project work by running __main__.py AND  installing it with pip and executing afterwards I found for this time is to add next lines to __main__.py:
from pathlib import Path
if __package__ is None:
    DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent
    sys.path.insert(0, str(DIR.parent))
    __package__ = DIR.name


How do you run it from the command line and from which directory?

Why __main__ is outside DIR_MODULES? __main__ is used for running packages in command line like python -m my_module. Also if you want import function foo() from module bar located in file spam.py - to do from bar import foo, you need to create bar.__init__.py file in which you import foo() directly from bar/spam.py.

__main__ .py is a main script and is named so and kept in project;s "root" directory because, as far as I understand, it must be so for pip installation using .toml file and to serve as an entry point.
DIR_MODULES will contain various functions. There will be also DIR_GUI for gui related parts of program etc
I followed this video from Real Python:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v6tALyc4C10
